# asyncTask нельзя использовать для выполнения запроса по сети?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

asyncTask у меня на вход принимает URL. и загружает данные. Но вскоре мне нужно кликнуть по другой кнопке и на вход ему идет другой URL, но воспользоваться этим asyncTask  я уже не могу. Но запросы нужно делать не в главном потоке и советуют использовать asyncTask для выполнения запроса. Но а как же быть с частыми запросами?

Comment: каждый раз создавать запрос как new asyncTask ?

Comment: Если да, то как правильно в методе asyncTask прописать, чтобы после выполнения он погиб. ИЛи учитывая тот факт что я его создал как new без сохранения его в переменную,а значит на него нет никаких ссылок, он погибнет сам по себе?

Comment: GC его сам уберет из памяти.

Comment: По вопросу -- посмотрите в сторону, например, OkHttp.